# react ts withRouter connect error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

i can not connect withRouter and connect.
Here is error i got:

```
(184,27): error TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<any>>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<any, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<any>; }' provides no match for the signature '(props: RouteComponentProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

Here is code:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MainPage));
```

Comment: This seems to be a type error from your typescript setup?

Comment: maybe, what could be wrong with my TS setup ? i have installed 2.6.2 TS

Comment: No, I mean you should look better at the error, it clearly states that your types are incompatible. What would be wrong with it, is hard to know, as the shared code is probably insufficient to make an accurate breakdown of your problem

Comment: Here is simple version of code: https://plnkr.co/edit/sdD0wDq3nb4JmTxGmDYK?p=catalogue

Answer (score 3):

Your props interface should extend RouteComponentProps. The type variable passed to `RouteComponentProps` should describe your intended **params**.

For example, if you expect two params (blogName and blogId) and a few props (logo and items) on this Route, then your full component props would look like:

```
interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps<{ blogName: string, blogId: number  }> {
  className?: string
  logo?: React.ReactNode
  items?: Array<INavItem>
}
```

Note in the following image how VSCode is correctly picking up my params:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shoopik is correct in the comments above:

The type that `withRouter` expects does not match the type you are passing to it. I believe this is a result of the way you are passing these interfaces to `React.Component`.

I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using for your `MainPage` props type (the `any & RouteProps` bit), but you may want to try declaring that interface explicitly with something like:

```
export interface MainPageProps extends RouteProps{
    /* you can add additional properties in here*/
}
```

And then use this to declare your `MainPage` class likeso:

`class MainPage extends React.Component<MainPageProps, any>`